# Polytopal domains in non-archimedean torus

Tags: rigid-analytic-geometry, non-archimedean-fields, berkovich-geometry

Given a non-archimedean field $\mathbb K$, there is a natural map
$$
\mathrm{val}: (\mathbb K^*)^n\to\mathbb R^n$$
(See Section 4 of Gubler's [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-007-0048-z)).
Gubler mentions there $\mathrm{val}$ is a continuous map. So, for a rational polytope $\Delta\subset\mathbb R^n$, the preimage $\mathrm{val}^{-1}(\Delta)$ should be closed since so is $\Delta$. But, it is known (like Proposition 4.1 there) that the preimage $\mathrm{val}^{-1}(\Delta)$ is actually a Weierstrass domain and seems to be open. Anyway, I get confused about the topology.

The very question I would like to ask is as follows: Gubler's Proposition 4.4 (e) states that if $\Delta'\subset \Delta$ is another rational polytope, then

> $\mathrm{val}^{-1}(\Delta')\subset\mathrm{val}^{-1}(\Delta)$ is an open immersion **if and only if** $\Delta'$ is a closed face of $\Delta$.

The "if" part is ok for me, but I have trouble in understanding the "only if" part. Imagine $\Delta$ is very large so that $\mathrm{val}^{-1}(\Delta)$ is approximately the whole torus $(\mathbb K^*)^n$, and we already know $\mathrm{val}^{-1}(\Delta')$ is a Weiestrass domain in $(\mathbb K^*)^n$. So we should expect it to be also open in $\mathrm{val}^{-1}(\Delta)$. But this contradicts to the above statement. Where is my mistake?

Maybe this is a stupid question and I am not an expert, but I get really confused. Thank you for any help!

Comment: You got the statement wrong: the open immersion is not the map between the Weierstrass domains, but the induced map between their reductions.

Comment: @JérômePoineau Thanks! So, let put it in a simpler way: if $\Delta'\subset \Delta$ is not a closed face, then is $\mathrm{val}^{-1}(\Delta')$ an *open subspace* of $\mathrm{val}^{-1}(\Delta)$?

Comment: You should make clear which space and which topology you use: the Berkovich analytification of $\mathbb{G}_m^n$? Then, I do not see how $\textrm{val}^{-1}(\Delta')$ could be ever be open except when it is the whole thing. Do you have any example?

Comment: @JérômePoineau Let's say we are in the category of the classical rigid analytic space and let's even consider the special case $\Delta'=\{0\}$. It seems strange to me why $\mathrm{val}^{-1}(\Delta')$ is not open in $\mathrm{val}^{-1}(\Delta)$, because both are open in the whole $\mathbb G_m^n$, if we consider subspace topology (or maybe not).

Comment: OK. I had the Berkovich picture in mind where affinoid domains are closed but not open in general. Anyway, $\mathrm{val}^{-1}(\Delta') \subset \mathrm{val}^{-1}(\Delta')$ is an embedding of an affinoid domain, so it would indeed be an open immersion in rigid geometry.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification! Now I think I understand. The issue is we should be more careful for Berkovich topology, but this is ok for rigid geometry.

Comment: Yes, opens in rigid geometry need not be open in Berkovich theory, so you should really be clear on which setting you use.